How to predict price behavior according to model predictions for a week ahead?
I wrote the simplest linear regression model (I'm a noob, please don't scold me; this is my first model) to predict the price of solana, I would like to get some advice or tips on how to improve. The main question is: how can I make a prediction, for example, a week ahead, and visualize it?
preprocessing
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
from sklearn.metrics import (
    accuracy_score,
    mean_absolute_error,
    mean_squared_error,
    r2_score,
    precision_score,
    recall_score
)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.1f}'.format

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/1/Desktop/data_ml/solana-historical-data.csv') # train data
price_sol_pred = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/1/Desktop/data_ml/solana-historical-data-test-ml.csv') # test data

df = df.rename(columns={'Дата': 'date',
                        'Открытие': 'opening_price',
                        'Макс': 'max_price',
                        'Мин': 'min_price',
                        'Средняя': 'avg_price',
                        'Закрытие': 'closing_price',
                        'Изм.': 'change_%',
                        'Объём': 'volume',
                        'Изм. Объема': 'change_volume',
                        'Капитализ.': 'market_cap',
                        'Изм. Капитализ.': 'change_market_cap'
                        })

price_sol_pred = price_sol_pred.rename(columns={'Дата': 'date',
                                                'Открытие': 'opening_price',
                                                'Макс': 'max_price',
                                                'Мин': 'min_price',
                                                'Средняя': 'avg_price',
                                                'Закрытие': 'closing_price',
                                                'Изм.': 'change_%',
                                                'Объём': 'volume',
                                                'Изм. Объема': 'change_volume',
                                                'Капитализ.': 'market_cap',
                                                'Изм. Капитализ.': 'change_market_cap'
                                                })

def convert_to_float(ds, columns):
    for column in columns:
        ds[column] = (ds[column].str.replace('$', '').str.replace(',', '').astype('float'))
    return ds


df = convert_to_float(df,
                      ['opening_price',
                       'max_price',
                       'min_price',
                       'avg_price',
                       'closing_price',
                       'volume',
                       'market_cap'])

price_sol_pred = convert_to_float(price_sol_pred,
                      ['opening_price',
                       'max_price',
                       'min_price',
                       'avg_price',
                       'closing_price',
                       'volume',
                       'market_cap'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['day_num'] = df['date'].dt.dayofweek

price_sol_pred['date'] = pd.to_datetime(price_sol_pred['date'])
price_sol_pred['day_num'] = price_sol_pred['date'].dt.dayofweek

df.dropna(inplace=True)
price_sol_pred.dropna(inplace=True)
price_sol_pred = price_sol_pred.drop('closing_price', axis=1)

linear regression model
RANDOM_STATE = 42

X = df.drop('closing_price', axis=1)
y = df['closing_price']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(
    X,
    y,
    random_state=RANDOM_STATE)

cat_col_names = ['day_num']
num_col_names = ['opening_price', 'change_%', 'volume', 'change_volume']

encoder = OneHotEncoder(drop='first', sparse=False)
X_train_ohe = encoder.fit_transform(X_train[cat_col_names])
X_test_ohe = encoder.transform(X_test[cat_col_names])
encoder_col_names = encoder.get_feature_names()

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scaled = scaler.fit_transform(X_train[num_col_names])
X_test_scaled = scaler.transform(X_test[num_col_names])

X_train_ohe = pd.DataFrame(X_train_ohe, columns=encoder_col_names)
X_test_ohe = pd.DataFrame(X_test_ohe, columns=encoder_col_names)

X_train_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_train_scaled, columns=num_col_names)
X_test_scaled = pd.DataFrame(X_test_scaled, columns=num_col_names)

X_train = pd.concat([X_train_ohe, X_train_scaled], axis=1)
X_test = pd.concat([X_test_ohe, X_test_scaled], axis=1)

model_lr = LinearRegression()
model_lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
predictions = model_lr.predict(X_test)

metrics
r2 = r2_score(y_test, predictions)
print(f'R2 = {r2:.3f}')
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, predictions)
print(f'MAE = {mae:.3f}')
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, predictions)
print(f'MSE = {mse:.3f}')
rmse = np.sqrt(mse)
print(f'RMSE = {rmse:.3f}')

R2 = 0.997
MAE = 2.044
MSE = 10.737
RMSE = 3.277
residuals = y_test - predictions
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(20, 10))
axes[0].hist(residuals)
axes[0].set_title('Histogram of residual distribution')
axes[0].set_xlabel('Remains')

axes[1].scatter(predictions, residuals)
axes[1].set_xlabel('Model predictions')
axes[1].set_ylabel('Remains')
axes[1].set_title('Scatterplot')
plt.show()


the residuals of the model are distributed normally, the spread of the variance looks strange, but it seems to me that this is the nature of the data
prediction
cat_col_names = ['day_num']
num_col_names = ['opening_price', 'change_%', 'volume', 'change_volume']

sol_ml_ohe = encoder.transform(price_sol_pred[cat_col_names])
encoder_col_names = encoder.get_feature_names()


sol_ml_scaled = scaler.transform(price_sol_pred[num_col_names])
X_test_ohe = pd.DataFrame(sol_ml_ohe, columns=encoder_col_names)
X_test_scaled = pd.DataFrame(sol_ml_scaled, columns=num_col_names)

X_test = pd.concat([X_test_ohe, X_test_scaled], axis=1)

predictions_sol_price = model_lr.predict(X_test)
price_sol_pred['predicted_price'] = predictions_sol_price

I would like to see advice on whether the model is written correctly and most importantly how to make forecasts with a linear regression model. I am also confused by the fact that the model is too accurate. Maybe I made a mistake somewhere.
